# Spark 2.0 CSV Error

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0, databricks

I am upgrading to spark 2 from 1.6 and am having an issue reading in CSV files. In spark 1.6 I would have something like this to read in a CSV file.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
.option("header", "true")
.load(fileName)
```

Now I use the following code as given in the documentation:

```
val df = spark.read
.option("header", "true")
.csv(fileName)
```

This results in the following error when running:

`"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple     sources found for csv     (org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat,   com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource15), please specify the fully qualified class name."`

I assume this is because I still had the spark-csv dependency, however I removed that dependency and rebuilt the application and I still get the same error. How is the databricks dependency still being found once I have removed it?

Answer (score 3):

The error message means you have `--packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0` option while you run `spark-shell` or have those jars in your class path. Please check your class path and remove that.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't add any jars to my class path.
I use this to load csv file in spark shell(2.3.1).
`val df = spark.sqlContext.read.csv('path')`

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer and add short explanation why/how this code solves issue?